# Maui BazorWebView. Information Needed

Tags: webview, blazor, maui

I currently trying out Maui and would like to keep the Maui Shell and components as the base platform.
But I have found that the CollectionView with about 20 or 30 complex items becomes almost impossible to scroll and gets odd display issues. So I'm currently looking at doing the more complex displays in Razor. I have been using Razor on the web for a while and have had no problems showing many thousands of items. So 50 or 60 complex display items on a mobile phone should not be a problem.
What I would like to do is not host the whole application in the BlazoeWebView, but just call up a single Razor page at a time in the BlazorWebView by either changing the "HostPage" or the "RootComponents".

```
 <BlazorWebView HostPage="wwwroot/index.html">
        <BlazorWebView.RootComponents>
            <RootComponent Selector="#app" ComponentType="{x:Type local:Main}" />
        </BlazorWebView.RootComponents>
 </BlazorWebView>
```

So far I have been unable to find the correct application structure to allow this.
Any information on how to achieve this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
I figured it out.

Set up an XML namespace with the path to your razor view.
Leave the HostPage at "wwwroot/index.html"
Leave the Selector at Selector="#app"
Set the ContentType to the name of your Razor page.

<ContentView xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
            xmlns:view="**clr-namespace:Your.Path.To.Razor.Page">
    <BlazorWebView HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                   VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                   HostPage="wwwroot/index.html">
        <BlazorWebView.RootComponents>
            <RootComponent Selector="#app" ComponentType="{x:Type view:Razor_Page_Name}" />
        </BlazorWebView.RootComponents>
    </BlazorWebView>
</ContentView>
```

Comment: Please mark it as answered so that it will help others who have similar problem here.Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: Hi @terry151151 , When I do the same, I lost layout (bootstrap master page)? Did you achive to keep it, or you don't you it?

Comment: I didn't have to change anything else that I know of. I'm not using the Shell navigation so I removed all the Blazor  navigation. So main MainLayout.razor reads: "@inherits LayoutComponentBase

<div class="page">
 <main>
  <article class="content px-4">
   @Body
  </article>
 </main>
</div>
"